# Blue J Java - Beginner - Playing two tracks at once issue

Tags: java, bluej

I'm relatively new to Java and just reading through a book a friend lent me.

The question says

If you play two tracks without stopping the first one, both will play simultaneously.
This is not very useful. Change your program so that a playing track is automatically
stopped when another track is started

This is what it looks like so far:

```
public void playTrack(int index)
{
    if(indexValid(index)) {
        Track track = tracks.get(index);
        player.startPlaying(track.getFilename());
        track.incrementCount();
        System.out.println("Now playing: " + track.getArtist() + " - " + 
track.getTitle());
       }
```

My plan was to add another else if statement and then to somehow say if one song is playing then stop the current and start the next, but I'm unsure how to do this.

Apologies this my first time on this forum and I'm very new to java.

Here's the full code for this class with API

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

/**

 */
            public class MusicOrganizer
            {
                // An ArrayList for storing music tracks.
                private ArrayList<Track> tracks;
                // A player for the music tracks.
                private MusicPlayer player;
                // A reader that can read music files and load them as tracks.
                private TrackReader reader;

                /**
                 * Create a MusicOrganizer
                 */
                public MusicOrganizer()
                {
                    tracks = new ArrayList<>();
                    player = new MusicPlayer();
                    reader = new TrackReader();
                    readLibrary("../audio");
                    System.out.println("Music library loaded. " + getNumberOfTracks() + " tracks.");
                    System.out.println();
                }

                /**
                 * Add a track file to the collection.
                 * @param filename The file name of the track to be added.
                 */
                public void addFile(String filename)
                {
                    tracks.add(new Track(filename));
                }

                /**
                 * Add a track to the collection.
                 * @param track The track to be added.
                 */
                public void addTrack(Track track)
                {
                    tracks.add(track);
                }

                /**
                 * Play a track in the collection.
                 * @param index The index of the track to be played.
                 */
                public void playTrack(int index)
                {
                    if(indexValid(index)) {
                        Track track = tracks.get(index);
                        player.startPlaying(track.getFilename());
                        System.out.println("Now playing: " + track.getArtist() + " - " + track.getTitle());
                    }
                }

                /**
                 * Return the number of tracks in the collection.
                 * @return The number of tracks in the collection.
                 */
                public int getNumberOfTracks()
                {
                    return tracks.size();
                }

                /**
                 * List a track from the collection.
                 * @param index The index of the track to be listed.
                 */
                public void listTrack(int index)
                {
                    System.out.print("Track " + index + ": ");
                    Track track = tracks.get(index);
                    System.out.println(track.getDetails());
                }

                /**
                 * Show a list of all the tracks in the collection.
                 */
                public void listAllTracks()
                {
                    System.out.println("Track listing: ");

                    for(Track track : tracks) {
                        System.out.println(track.getDetails());
                    }
                    System.out.println();
                }

                /**
                 * List all tracks by the given artist.
                 * @param artist The artist's name.
                 */
                public void listByArtist(String artist)
                {
                    for(Track track : tracks) {
                        if(track.getArtist().contains(artist)) {
                            System.out.println(track.getDetails());
                        }
                    }
                }

                /**
                 * Remove a track from the collection.
                 * @param index The index of the track to be removed.
                 */
                public void removeTrack(int index)
                {
                    if(indexValid(index)) {
                        tracks.remove(index);
                    }
                }

                /**
                 * Play the first track in the collection, if there is one.
                 */
                public void playFirst()
                {
                    if(tracks.size() > 0) {
                        player.startPlaying(tracks.get(0).getFilename());
                    }
                }

                /**
                 * Stop the player.
                 */
                public void stopPlaying()
                {
                    player.stop();
                }

                /**
                 * Determine whether the given index is valid for the collection.
                 * Print an error message if it is not.
                 * @param index The index to be checked.
                 * @return true if the index is valid, false otherwise.
                 */
                private boolean indexValid(int index)
                {
                    // The return value.
                    // Set according to whether the index is valid or not.
                    boolean valid;

                    if(index < 0) {
                        System.out.println("Index cannot be negative: " + index);
                        valid = false;
                    }
                    else if(index >= tracks.size()) {
                        System.out.println("Index is too large: " + index);
                        valid = false;
                    }
                    else {
                        valid = true;
                    }
                    return valid;
                }

                private void readLibrary(String folderName)
                {
                    ArrayList<Track> tempTracks = reader.readTracks(folderName, ".mp3");

                    // Put all thetracks into the organizer.
                    for(Track track : tempTracks) {
                        addTrack(track);
                    }
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  Please [take the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) to see how the site works and what questions are on topic here, and edit your question accordingly.  See also: [Why is "Can someone help me?" not an actual question?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284236)

Comment: Do you have control over the `MusicPlayer` code also?  If so, you can alter `MusicPlayer.startPlaying()` to first call `stop()` on itself.  Alternatively, I suppose you can just call `stop()` yourself in `MusicOrganizer.playTrack()`

Answer (score 0):

Before starting the track specified by `index` you would have to stop all other tracks by doing something like the following:

```
for(int i = 0; i < tracks.size(); i++) {
    if(i != trackToPlay) {
        player.stop(tracks.get(i));
    }
}
```

Comment: I've tried adding that to begin with but it's expecting a ; after i = 0, for when you're saying i in small than tracks.size(); i++.

Comment: Oh, thats a typo. It should be `for(int i = 0; i < tracks.size(); i++)`

Comment: but now i have to define the trackToPlay variable - is that your intention?

Comment: That's the parameter called `index` in your `playTrack` method.

Comment: Ok i'm confused because we haven't defined the variable trackToPlay, so my IDE is throwing this error: 'cannot find symbol - variable trackToPlay'.

Comment: Yeah, replace it by `index`

Comment: Ok so this is what I have put now:
`public void playTrack(int index)
   {
        for(int i = 0; i < tracks.size(); i++) {
       if(i != index) {
        player.stop(tracks.get(i));
   }
}`
Now I am getting this error:

method stop in class MusicPlayer cannot be applied to given types;

required: no argumentsl; found: Track; reasons: actual and formal arguments lists differ in length

Comment: What I've shown in my answer is pseudocode. That's code that is functionally correct, but has to be changed in order to make it work. Like changing the `trackToPlay` to `index`. I don't know which API you're using to play back audio (you should have put that in the question).  So I assumed that you're using the `AudioPlayer` built into java. Based on that assumption, I provided an answer that would _probably_ work with that API. What might be, is that you're using a totally different API. Because of that my answer doesn't work. So you need to provide what API you're using in the question.

Comment: Hi thanks for your response. I've updated the original request now and included the API sorry for not providing this originally.